# phpunit xml configuration colors instruction dosen't work

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I define a **phpunit.xml** configuration file for my unit tests. In this file I instruct to show colors in the unit tests results like this:

```
<phpunit
   ... 
   colors="true"
   ... 
</phpunit>
```

When I run the tests in the command line it is all ok, except that I get no green and red colors in the results.

If I delete the configuration file and use the parameter `--color=always` in the command line then I get the result with colors.

In the configuration file I already try to change `colors="true"` to `colors="always"` with no result.

Is any problem with my configuration file?

Here is my phpunit.xml configuration file:

```
<phpunit
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/5.1/phpunit.xsd"
  backupGlobals="true"
  backupStaticAttributes="false"
  cacheTokens="false"
  colors="true"
  convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
  convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
  convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
  forceCoversAnnotation="false"
  mapTestClassNameToCoveredClassName="false"
  printerClass="PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter"
  processIsolation="false"
  stopOnError="false"
  stopOnFailure="false"
  stopOnIncomplete="false"
  stopOnSkipped="false"
  stopOnRisky="false"
  testSuiteLoaderClass="PHPUnit_Runner_StandardTestSuiteLoader"
  timeoutForSmallTests="1"
  timeoutForMediumTests="10"
  timeoutForLargeTests="60"
  verbose="false">
 <testsuites>
   <testsuite name="examples">
     <directory>/home/miguelbgouveia/Documents/projects/joomla/tests</directory>
     <file>test_example.php</file>
   </testsuite>
 </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

And the version of phpunit is 5.1.2

Comment: What phpunit  version are you using? Can you provide full config?

Comment: I am using version 5.1.2. Is the version that are in the official phpunit docker container.

Comment: yep got the same problem. It works on the CLI, but not when setting it on `phpunit.xml`

Comment: Whats your value for `$TERM` ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by removing the line

```
printerClass="PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter"
```

It looked like before, but with colors. Hope this fixes your problem too